# Send text/input to all tabs

Tags: gnome-terminal, terminal-multiplexer

I'm using the Gnome terminal and am logged into different servers on each tab. Is there a way to send the same text/command to all the tabs at once?

Comment: Logged using ssh, right?

Comment: Yes that's correct. Using ssh. I know about multiplexing but am just wondering if this ability comes native with GNOME Terminal.

Answer (score 6):

#### Multixterm

There's a tool called [`multixterm`](http://expect.sourceforge.net/example/multixterm.man.html). It uses `xterm` terminals. You can invoke it like so:

```
$ multixterm
```

And once up you'll be presented with a GUI.

[image: ss of gui]

You can then start spinning up `xterm` windows by clicking the `new xterm` button. Here for example I've invoked 2. If you then click on the primary window, you can start typing commands in both windows simultaneously:

[image: ss of xtems]

#### keyboardcast

Appears to only be available on Ubuntu, looks similar to multixterm.

*excerpt*

> The purpose of keyboardcast is to allow you to send keystrokes to multiple
>   X windows at once. This allows you, for example, to control a number of
>   terminals connected to different but similar hosts for purposes of mass-
>   administration.
>
> You can also select non-terminals. If you come up with a reasonable use
>   for this ability I'd be interested in hearing about it.
>
> The program can select windows to send to either by matching their titles
>   (using a substring) or by clicking on them (in a method similar to GIMP's
>   screenshot feature).
>
> The program also features the ability to spawn off multiple instances of
>   gnome-terminal executing a single command on multiple arguments (for example
>   executing 'ssh' on several hosts). The gnome-terminals are invoked with
>   the profile 'keyboardcast' if it exists (so, for example, your font size
>   can be smaller).

- [Control Multiple Terminals Simultaneously](http://www.frozenindustries.com/2006/09/21/control-multiple-terminals-simultaneously/)
- [keyboardcast on launchpad](https://launchpad.net/keyboardcast)

#### Terminator

If you want to forgo using `gnome-terminal` there's also [Terminator](http://gnometerminator.blogspot.com/p/introduction.html). Specifically this bullet from the feature list:

> Simultaneous typing to arbitrary groups of terminals

Here's an example where I'm broadcasting the command `ls` to 4 different `terminator` windows.

[image: ss #1]